# Using Jira's API to add an attachment to an issue

Tags: jira, attachment

I was wondering if Jira's REST API supports the ability to add an attachment to an issue (existing or new) along with uploading the attachment too?  Looking at the API documentation I did not see anything however maybe i missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the method you're after:

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id339692

Answer (score 0):

After you create the issue, you can click on more actions tab of that particular issue.

You would be able to attach files and attach screenshot.

Correct me if I am wrong in understanding your requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to do this through the REST API, not the application itself

Answer (score 0):

### in Python:

jira = JIRA(options="Jira_Server_URL", basic_auth=("userID", "Password"))
jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment="attachment_path")

Replace Jira_Server_URL, userID, Password and attachment_path accordingly.